# Unpack values from nested dictionaries with depth level = 1

Tags: python, dictionary, set, distinct-values, unpack

Is there a more elegant way to unpack values from nested dictionaries (depth level = 1) in a set?

```
d = {1: {10: 'a',
         11: 'b'},
     2: {20: 'a',
         21: 'c'}}


print(set(c for b in [[*set(a.values())] for a in d.values()] for c in b))
# {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `values` of nested `dict` and add in `set`.

```
d = {1: {10: 'a',
         11: 'b'},
     2: {20: 'a',
         21: 'c'}}

res = set(v for key,val in d.items() for v in val.values())

print(res)
# {'a', 'b', 'c'}
```